# react native Navigator navigationBar - has 3/4 method that's never being used?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am looking at this file https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorNavigationBar.js, have read it several times. cant seem to find where are the following methods are being used:

```
immediatelyRefresh
_getReusableProps
_updateIndexProgress
updateProgress
```

`updateProgress` is the entry point for `updateIndexProgress` and `getReusableProps`, but i dont see anywhere in the file where its used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all probably called from other components. For example, in Navigator.js (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/Navigator.js):

```
_transitionBetween: function(fromIndex, toIndex, progress) {
    this._transitionSceneStyle(fromIndex, toIndex, progress, fromIndex);
    this._transitionSceneStyle(fromIndex, toIndex, progress, toIndex);
    var navBar = this._navBar;
    if (navBar && navBar.updateProgress && toIndex >= 0 && fromIndex >= 0) {
      navBar.updateProgress(progress, fromIndex, toIndex);
    }
  },
```